# jQuery validation addMethod to check if field1 < field2, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery validation to validate a form like this:

IdFrom ________        IdTo ______________

The checks that I'm performing are:

IdFrom:

- Needs to be a number
- Is required if IdTo is entered
- Should be < IdTo if IdTo is entered

IdTo:

- Needs to be a number

My Code:

```
              jQuery.validator.addMethod("fromLessThanTo", function(value, element){
                      if(($("#IdTo").val().length <= 0))
                              return true;
                    return($("#IdTo").val() > $("#IdFrom").val());
              }, "From value cannot be greater than the To value"); 

              $("#IdFrom").rules('add', {
                    digits : true,
                    required : {                    
                            depends: function(element){
                                    return($("#IdTo").val() > 0);
                            },
                    fromLessThanTo : true 
                    },        
                    messages:         {
                            digits: "Please enter a positive number",
                            required: "Please enter the Id From" 
                    }        
              });

              $("#IdTo").rules('add', {
                    digits : true,
                    messages:         {
                            digits: "Please enter a positive number"                       
                            }
```

The code does not work in checking if From < To. Would really appreciate insight into why this happens. Thank you!

Comment: Might not be a bad idea to show us the relevant HTML markup of the form too.

Answer (score 1):

Try fixing all the syntax errors...

```
$("#IdFrom").rules('add', {
    digits: true,
    required: {                    
        depends: function(element){
            return($("#IdTo").val() > 0);
        },                  // <- superfluous comma
                            // <- missing a },
    fromLessThanTo: true    // <- missing a comma
    },                      // <- remove this }, 
    messages: {
        digits: "Please enter a positive number",
        required: "Please enter the Id From"
    }        
});

$("#IdTo").rules('add', {
    digits: true,
    messages: {
        digits: "Please enter a positive number"                       
    }
                            // <- missing a });
```

So it ends up looking like this...

```
$("#IdFrom").rules('add', {
    digits: true,
    required: {                    
        depends: function(element) {
            return($("#IdTo").val() > 0);
        }
    },
    fromLessThanTo: true,
    messages: {
        digits: "Please enter a positive number",
        required: "Please enter the Id From"
    }        
});

$("#IdTo").rules('add', {
    digits: true,
    messages: {
        digits: "Please enter a positive number"                       
    }
});
```